# how to count the number of "n" alone instead of n in the words?

Tags: python

I have a list of this:

> 'mor:co|remember pro|you v|count-PAST', 'mor:det:num|one det:num|two
>   det:num|three det:num|four det:num|five', 'mor:pro:wh|what mod|do&PAST
>   pro|you v|bring n:prop|Ursula', 'mor:pro:sub|I v|bring&PAST qn|some
>   n|puppet-PL', 'mor:pro|you v|want inf|to v|look adv|in coord|and
>   v|see',......

How do I count the number of `n` standing alone, omitting occurrences inside words.

(The symbol `n` stands for noun, so I want to count those but ignore where it occurs in words - e.g. `count-PAST`, `det:num`).

Comment: You need a grammar to describe this string and lexer/parser to pull it apart appropriately.  Scanning or regex won't do.

Comment: Do you just want `r'\bn\b'` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO3mQ5/1))?

Comment: so what is considered n alone `n:prop|` and `n|puppet-PL`?

Comment: You could `s.count('n:')` for each string in your list, but this certainly looks like the output of something like [`nltk.corpus`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.html) you should use your library appropriately

Comment: Yes. I only want r'\bn\b'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lookahead and lookbehind:

```
lines="""'mor:co|remember pro|you v|count-PAST', 'mor:det:num|one det:num|two det:num|three det:num|four det:num|five', 'mor:pro:wh|what mod|do&PAST pro|you v|bring n:prop|Ursula', 'mor:pro:sub|I v|bring&PAST qn|some n|puppet-PL', 'mor:pro|you v|want inf|to v|look adv|in coord|and v|see'"""


import re
print(re.findall("(?<=\s)n(?=[\|:])",lines))
['n', 'n']
```

Which matches `n:prop|` and `n|puppet-PL`, presuming there is always a space before and a `|` or `:` after.

Depending on how you data is structured you could also maybe use translate:

```
print(lines.translate({ord(":"):" ",ord("|"): " "}).split().count("n"))
2
```

For python2:

```
from string import maketrans
tbl = maketrans(":|","  ")
lines.translate(tbl).split().count("n")
```

Translate is more efficient:

```
In [8]: tbl = maketrans(":|","  ")

In [9]: timeit lines.translate(tbl).split().count("n")
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.07 µs per loop

In [10]: r = re.compile("(?<=[\s])n(?=[\|:])")

In [11]: timeit len(r.findall(lines))
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.27 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much. BTW, how do I count the number of n?

Comment: The len will be the count